# Is it possible to control MPU6000 with Maxon controller Board?

Tags: arduino, imu, controller

I am developing a robotic wrist in which I have two DC Motor+encoder pairs connected to a Maxon Escon Module 50/5 each. To control that the output of the wrist is correct, I want to place an IMU unit at the end to measure orientation. The MPU6000 seems like a cheap and easy solution. The setup would look like this:
[image]

The MPU would be connected to VCC, GND pins 11&12 and to two Analog In pins 27&29. I have been doing some research but there doesn't seem to be anybody who tried this in the past. Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Best,
Chusi

Comment: [how to ask a good question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andyaka very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you do not know what it is you really need, but this should have been obvious from skimming the functionality of the Maxon and MPU. Or even just looking at the block diagram you provided.

The MPU6000 communicates over I2C or SPI. It does not communicate over analog lines so there is no point to connecting it to the Maxon's analog inputs.

There was a possibility that the digital inputs  could support I2C or SPI, but if you skim the functionality of the Maxon you will see this is not the case. The digital and analog I/O on the Maxon are just for simple control and monitoring for motor driver use.

But on top of all of this, you cannot expect the Maxon to just know how to communicate with the MPU. The Maxon would need the capability to programmed like a microcontroller or processor. But it is just a motor driver. Nothing more.

So, no, you need a processor or microcontroller to communicate with the MPU and then command the Maxon. The good news is, this is not difficult or expensive. Even an Arduino could probably do it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful answer